# Top of View Hidden by NavigatorIOS in TabBarIOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a `TabBarIOS` as a main container, and each tab loads a `NavigatorIOS` component which holds (for example) a `View`. My problem is that the top of the `View` is hidden behind the `NavigatorIOS`. No styles on anything - this project is brand new.

Am I missing something that would allow the `View` to automatically adjust its top to fit inside the `NavigatorIOS` (which would automatically adjust its bottom to fit inside the `TabBarIOS`) like in native/Xcode?

Or, do I need to calculate the heights and drop in padding? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If you set `translucent` to `false`, it will adjust the spacing as I desired. But with `translucent` equal to `true`, it goes full height behind.